# Working only with gedit/vim. How to run JUnit class via command line

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, linux-mint

I am working on Linux Mint 14. I installed junit and I verified that it is on the PATH. In my home folder I have a class named testClass.class and in it I have defined test methods. When I try to run the program I get the following error:

```
lazarevsky@linuxbox ~ $ java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner testClass.class 
Class not found "testClass.class"
```

How to I proceed? What am I doing wrong? note that I am not using a full-blown IDE but just a text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner testClass
```

1. you should add . (the current directory) to classpath
2. you should use class name which is testClass not testClass.class

**EDIT**

first, you should read the doc of junit. there is a lot of manuals. 
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki

If you use junit4, you can easily start like this:

1. download junit-4.11.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar from junit site.
2. create a TestCase.java file like this:

> ```
> import org.junit.Test;
> import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
> import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
>
> @RunWith(JUnit4.class)
> public class TestCase {
>     @Test
>     public void testA(){
>         org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(true);
>     }
> }
> ```

1. javac -cp junit-4.11.jar TestCase.java
2. java -cp .:junit-4.11.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestCase

then you can find the test results like this:

```
JUnit version 4.11
.
Time: 0.006

OK (1 test)
```

Comment: got this error now:  ~ $ java -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner testClass
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 169877536 in class file testClass
What does it mean?

Comment: @Dragan your class file is broken, compile it again. The magic value of a valid Java class is 0xCAFEBABE (the hex value of 3405691582), which is the first 4 bytes.

Comment: I changed it to .java instead of .class and tried to compile it but it cannot find the dependencies for junit declared at the top not can it interpret @Test. How do I include those references without using IDE?

Comment: lazarevsky@linuxbox ~ $ junit -v
JUnit 3.8.2 by Kent Beck and Erich Gamma
Usage: TestRunner [-wait] testCaseName, where name is the name of the TestCase class

Comment: @Dragan if you want to learn junit, you can start from junit4 now, the design of which is more modern, and easy to startup.

Comment: installed both jars and added them to /usr/local/bin and now it should be on the classpath correct? Tried it and got the following error --> lazarevsky@linuxbox ~ $ javac testClass.java 
testClass.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
    import org.junit.Test; testClass.java:5: error: package org.junit.runners does not exist
    import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
                            ^
testClass.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    @RunWith(JUnit4.class)
     ^
  symbol: class RunWith
testClass.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        @Test. What do you think is wrong now?

Comment: @Dragan No, add jar to bin is not add them to classpath. you should use java "-cp" argument to special classpath. like the above.

Comment: I don't get it. Where should I save the jar files or what environment variable should I change in order to get this to work? I followed your instructions, but I am not sure how to place them on the classpath? Please if you could only answer me this question.. Thank you so much

Comment: you can save the jar files anywhere you like. you can add it to CLASSPATH environment which can add these jars to every java's classpath. but you should avoid to use that methods, because it can cause a lot of side effects. you should always use -cp arguments to special classpath to current java process. I advice you figure out how to use java first.

Comment: Okay so finally it compiles.. Now when I run it I get the following error: lazarevsky@linuxbox ~ $ java -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner testClass
.F
Time: 0.001
There was 1 failure:
1) warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in testClass

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1,  Errors: 0

Comment: @Dragan javac -cp /usr/local/bin/junit-4.11.jar TestCase.java then java -cp .:/usr/local/bin/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/bin/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestCase

Answer (score 0):

add current directory to your classpath.

`java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar:. junit.textui.TestRunner testClass.class`